# Typescript question around variable assignments from an object

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain what's going on here?

```
let b; 
({a:b}={a:'1234'});
console.log("b=", b);
```

when i run above code, i get output `b=1234`.
I'm just trying to understand what's happening here. I'm new to typescript coming from Java background!

Comment: It’s object destructuring + assignment to a new variable. This is an ES6 syntax and has nothing to do with TypeScript.

Comment: See the docs: [Object destructuring:  Assignment separate from declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) (combined with *'Assigning to new variable names'*)

Comment: it answers my question, not something easy to get it naturally. i'll dig through docs around the ES6 object destructuring concept!

Comment: this might be easier to reason about if you write it as `let {a: b} = {a: '1234'}`